# Installling.exe using MSIEXEC in NSIS (Program doesn't install at all)

Tags: installation, nsis

I try to install a program (.exe)in the NSIS Script here is my code

```
;Install PDFXVIEWER
SetOutPath "$INSTDIR\PdfViewer"
File /r "file\PdfViewer\PDFXV.exe"  
ExecWait 'msiexec /i "file\PdfViewer\PDFXV.exe" /VERYSILENT /NORESTART /DIR="$INSTDIR\PdfViewer"'
```

However, during the installation i got a windows installer popup ! : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8Gdh.jpg

and the program is not installed at all.

Can anyone point me my error??

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

msiexec is for installing .msi files (And remember to use full paths). You should be able to execute the .exe file normally...

Comment: Your seem right however there is something wrong again look the post again ^^

Comment: @Anders: in the image linked in the question, the OP gets a help window about the CLI parameters for msiexec. It seems that `msiexec` does not understand what it is given as parameters. He should try by running the .exe directly.

Comment: @seki: Maybe that was unclear but when I said run the exe normally I meant directly...

Answer (score 1):

`exec` doc:

> Note that the file specified must exist on the target system, not the compiling system.

`"file\PdfViewer\PDFXV.exe"` is the file on the compiling computer, not the target system, you should change it to `"$INSTDIR\PdfViewer\PDFXV.exe"`